# How to suffle a ragged tensor in Tensorflow/Keras, using only tensorflow/keras operations

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to shuffle a rangged tensor

```
shuffleTest = tf.random.uniform(
                shape=[5, 8], minval=0, maxval=1000, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32, seed=None, name=None)
tf.random.shuffle(shuffleTest)
```

Works fine

```
digits = tf.ragged.constant([[3, 1, 4, 1], [], [5, 9, 2], [6], []])
tf.random.shuffle(digits)
```

Results in

```
ValueError: TypeError: object of type 'RaggedTensor' has no len()
```

Is there an elegant way to shuffle a ragged tensor, using only tensorflow/keras operations. This is because I am creating a pipeline that will run on TPUs.

So far I came up with this workaround

```
digits = tf.ragged.constant([[3, 1, 4, 1], [], [5, 9, 2], [6], []])
print(digits)
a = tf.random.shuffle(tf.range(digits.shape[0]))
b = tf.reshape(a, (digits.shape[0], 1))
shuffledDigits = tf.gather_nd(digits, b)
print(shuffledDigits)
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Converting it [to a tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor#to_tensor) before shuffling and then [back](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor#from_tensor) would do the trick, but probably defeat the purpose of using ragged: `tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(tf.random.shuffle(digits.to_tensor()), padding=0)`.

Comment: Hey Did you find a way? I'm also stuck on this